# Change currency format to show 4 decimal places instead of 2 globally

Tags: c#, .net

I have a working website, where I use this expression everywhere.

```
price.ToString("C")
```

It currently shows 2 decimal places, eg. $1.45

Now I need the website to show 4 decimal places, eg. $1.4515

Is there any easy way to change it globally?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't modify the default behavior of the format specifier, but you can do a a global search-and-replace in your project.  Assuming you're using Visual Studio, you can do a global search-and-replace (Ctrl-Shift-H) and replace `.ToString("C")` with `.ToString("C4")`.

Comment: Thanks - I found that I could also use `DataFormatString="{0:C4}"` in a Grid Column.

Comment: What happens if that `4` is in a variable?

Answer (score 4):

Can you overwrite thread's [CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture.aspx) and set [CurrencyDecimalDigits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencydecimaldigits.aspx)?